# Android: Why does the background of an AlertDialog change when I set the background of the items in its list

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

My situation is this: I have an `v7.AlertDialog` which is being populated by a list using `AlertDialog.Builder.setAdapter`.  When I have no background on the items in my list, the title and buttons on the adapter have a white background like so. [image]

However, once I add a color to the items in the list (via setting a background attribute on the adapter items), the background of the title and buttons change to the window background color like so: [image]

I pulled up the view in hierarchyviewer, and I noticed that this was happening because the title section and buttons on an `AlertDialog` have no background.  However, why does this cause them to have a white background when there is no background on the items in my Adapter? Shouldn't they still be colored with the window background?

I was able to solve this by setting the window background, but it still just seems like curious behavior to me.

The code for my adapter and view is pretty uninteresting.  The View is just

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/some_shade_of_gray">

    <!-- A LinearLayout with some TextViews -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_graphic"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the getView method in the adapter looks like.

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View toReturn = convertView;
    if (toReturn == null) {
        toReturn = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.address_view, parent, false);
        // Initialize a ViewHolder with a bunch of fields.
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) toReturn.getTag();
    // set some text in TextViews

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the code?

Comment: Some images would be well received too

Comment: Still have no clear idea about the `RelativeLayout`. Is it the row of the list in the `AlertDialog`? You set the bgcolor of the row and it changed the color of the background of the whole `AlertDialog`? Try `wrap_content` for the row height this: `<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/some_shade_of_gray">`

Comment: Yes, it is a single row in the ListView, and it changed the background of the whole AlertDialog.